Google Form Responses No Longer Showing in Spreadsheet
I have a Google form that is linked to a spreadsheet, response summaries have been coming in fine up until recently they have stopped showing. The responses are showing in the Google Responses Summary Page and when I unlink and link the spreadsheet, the responses are able to show in a new tab but I am needing them to show in the original tab I created that has various different conditional formats.
Ive seen online it is best to unlink and link the spreadsheet, which I have tried and it works.. however, it doesn't solve the problem of preventing this issue and it requires me to adjust the new tab that pulls from re-linking it by recreating and adjusting the conditional formats I made.
